# Date Comparison

Tags: vb.net

Here are the parts of My Program.

```
Table:SGinfo
-Birthdate
-Age
VB.net form
Label6.text Respectively "Update Age of all Guards in the list"
```

My question in my Database there is a record in the table that contains this ---> "7/25/2013"
How can i update a persons age by comparing only the Month and Day of the record in the databse in the Systems Month and Date also

Example

```
"7/15" Compare to database record like this "7/25/2013"
```

I dont know how to code this.

So please give a simple code about it TY.

Comment: Please explain further. Do you want to find the distance between the two dates? What is the value of the year portion in case of 7/15?

Comment: Do you mean the Date? Im using Here is Access and the field type of it is Text and It can Be field by a Date in format of "MM/DD/YYYY" for example i will save a date of "7/25/2013"  the program will Cut the date format until the "MM/DD" will remain like this "7/25" then i will compare to the date in my PC by the same format of "mm/dd" then if the statement is true the execute the command how can i embed that in sql command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the light of your explanation in the comment, you should read the value from the database and then split in on slash '/' character to get the chunks for date and month parts. Then afterwards, you can use `int.Parse()` to convert these chunks into numeric values and compare them against `DateTime.Now.Month` and `DateTime.Now.Day` parts.

An alternate is to use something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd")` and compare it directly to the DB value you read.

Comment: Sir 1 more Question, How can I Increase the age by in the Database?

Comment: Assuming im 19 years Old and I save My Information. Name: Paul Birthdate: 7/25/2013 This is the Simulation "If CP Date:"7/25" = Database Bdate:"7/25" then Update age +1" so i will Become 20. Oh by the way Happy B-day to me :D

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid having `Age` column altogether. You already are storing DOB, so computing the age should be trivial. This will also get you rid of all the update stuff you're going to do in this case. Always compute your Age at run-time, through a computed column or a query or an expression column in your DataTable at application level.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your Date from Database as a variable ..

```
Dim dBirth as DateTime = MyTable.Item("BirthDate") '---> get from table

If dBirth.Month = Now().Month AND dBirth.Day = Now().Day Then 

  'some code ...   

End If
```

Comment: Sir Can you please add The declaration in the Mytable i dont know how to declare it

Comment: @CrixalisPaul .. Google will help you .. keyword : datatable, oledbadapter etc ..

Answer (score 0):

if they are of same year then try, or change the `date1.Year` as you likr

```
    Dim date1, date2 As Date
    Dim lDate1 As String
    date1 = Date.Parse("7/25/2013")
    lDate1 = "7/15" + "/"   + date1.Year
    date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(lDate1 , "dd/MM/yyyy", Null)

     if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) > 0) 
      // which means ("date1 > date2")
     if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) == 0) 
     //which means ("date1 == date2");
     if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) < 0) 
     //which means ("date1 < date2")
```

**or**

```
Dim tSpan As TimeSpan
tSpan = date2 - date1
```

Comment: How can i use in my database